# Why are reputation points and badges not showing?

Tags: discussion, reputation, profile-page, account-suspension

While searching for a solution to my question, I found a user which has a good profile on Stack Overflow, but no reputation and badges. The user has answered many questions, but the reputation points are only 1. The following is a screen shot and user profile link:

[User Profile link](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4109841/nakka-chandra)

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The profile says:

> This account is temporarily suspended for voting irregularities. The suspension period ends in 12 hours.

Which is why reputation is displayed as 1.

This is by design. From the [official blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/):

> Depending on the severity of the problem behavior — and at the complete discretion of the moderator — your account will be placed in timed suspension for anywhere from 1 to 365 days. That means:
>
> - Your account will be locked at 1 reputation.
> - Your user page will have a visual indication that you are in timed suspension, and for how long.
> - You will be unable to vote, ask, answer, or comment.
>
> At the end of this timed suspension period, your reputation will be recalculated, and your account will resume as normal. We don’t hold grudges. The point of all this is to address the behavior. If the behavior improves, you are welcome back.